# Why does Spring Boot spawn 2 test containers with singleton container approach?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test, testcontainers

I'm using Spring-boot 2.5.3 with Junit 5

I am trying to test with a PostgresSQL test container. I need to use this same test container with integration test and repository test because it was having two instances in Docker.

Here is my base class where I initialize the container.

```
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertyRegistry;
import org.springframework.test.context.DynamicPropertySource;
import org.testcontainers.containers.PostgreSQLContainer;

public  class PostgresTestContainer {
    static final PostgreSQLContainer postgreSQLContainer;

    static {
        postgreSQLContainer = (PostgreSQLContainer) new PostgreSQLContainer("postgres:12")
                .withDatabaseName("test")
                .withUsername("postgres")
                .withPassword("postgres")
                .withReuse(true);

        postgreSQLContainer.start();
    }

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void datasourceConfig(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
        registry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer::getPassword);
        registry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer::getUsername);
    }
}
```

This is repository test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
class CustomerRepositoryTest extends PostgresTestContainer {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Test
    @Sql("/scripts/import.sql")
    public void findAllShouldGetAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> foundCustomers = customerRepository.findAll();
        assertThat(foundCustomers).isNotNull();
        assertThat(foundCustomers.size()).isEqualTo(3);
    }
}
```

This is another place where I need to use the same test container.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class BasicIT extends PostgresTestContainer {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @MockBean
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    @Test
    void shouldFailFetchingCustomersWhenDatabaseIsDown() {
        when(customerRepository.findAll()).thenThrow(new RuntimeException("Cannot connect to database."));
        ResponseEntity<String> result = this.testRestTemplate
                .exchange("/api/v1/customers", HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, String.class);
        assertEquals(500, result.getStatusCodeValue());
    }


    @Test
    public void shouldFetchAListOfCustomers(){
        ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> result = this.testRestTemplate
                .exchange("/api/v1/customers", HttpMethod.GET, HttpEntity.EMPTY, new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {});
        assertEquals(200, result.getStatusCodeValue());
    }
}
```

Running:

```
mvn clean install
```

This works, and all tests run.

But it opens two containers as shown in Docker image here.

How to use singleton container the correct way? I want to use only one.
[image: docker image for 2 test containers]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the container image names, the containers are different. The second container is your database (`postgres`), but the first one (`ryuk`) is an auxillary container, started by the `Testcontainer` library itself by default. `Ryuk` performs fail-safe cleanup of other containers ([documentation](https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/image_registry_rate_limiting/#which-images-are-used-by-testcontainers)) after they are not needed anymore. There is no need to worry about it, because it's tiny (~5Mb).

If you **absolutelly** sure that you don't need it, you can disable `ryuk` following [this instruction](https://www.testcontainers.org/features/configuration/#disabling-ryuk).